# What are the options to listen to http traffic from the flash program embedded into a web-page?

Tags: flash, http, traffic

Here is my situation in a nutshell: there is a flash program built and it's being embedded into different site pages. There is no ability to change the flash program and I want a small add-on (let's name it add-on) so it would extend the functionality of the flash program a little bit. Example: my flash program asks for a quote from the main server, I need to display some additional information regarding the quote requested.

The data is being returned by my server json-serialized and I can add any data to it, but as the flash program does not display additional information, I'd like it to show in a window, in a widget on the page or something alike.

Prerequisites:
a) Windows OS
b) Http traffic (req/resp) should be read as is by the addon and the addon will make necessary calculations/actions and (probably) additional requests if needed
c) The ability to show calculated results in any way so the end user could see
d) Preferably the add-on should be invoked only when certain requests are fired (for example http://url/get/quote/1234)
e) I'd prefer not doing any extra requests; getting extra data from http response being fetched by flash program is fine with me.

The options I believe are:

1. Greasemonkey script. Does not work as probably it can not read http traffic unless it's the main page url.
2. Firefox/Chrome addons. I read that Chrome forbids accessing the http requests, and I can not find any [API methods](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) for watching the http traffic. but I'm not sure about [Firefox API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/reference).
3. Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has a net panel which can track http(s) requests sent even by embedded Flash apps. See if that is what you want. It shows you the request and response headers POST content (if any) and the response content.

Comment: Tools like Firebug, Fiddler and others are well-known, but they do not suit my needs as I have to build my own tool that is invoked automatically (once installed, of course).

Comment: Well, firebug is opensource, so you could check it out

Comment: Firebug lacks automatic invocation like GreaseMonkey does (meaning @include). I'm going to check out all other options. Thanks, Pranav for your answers.